Android studio type define multiple times
i encounter with this problem
Type com.kason.pos.cashier.tablet.ui.POSFragment$3 is defined multiple times: 

KASONPOS/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/kason/pos/cashier/tablet/ui/POSFragment$3 2.class
KASONPOS/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/kason/pos/cashier/tablet/ui/POSFragment$3.class

i never edited the build
i edited the activity code then suddenly show this error
i try find the multiple i cannot find the multiple definition
